# Java Swing FlowLayout in Vaadin

Tags: java, swing, vaadin, flowlayout

As some of you might know there is a Layout that is called `FlowLayout` in the Java Swing Framework. To spice things up a little I started using Vaadin instead of Swing. Everything works fine except that I haven't found an easy alternative to the classic Swing `FlowLayout`.

I want to place Components next to each other until the horizontal space of a row is filled and the layout starts placing components in a new row. I tried using the Horizontal Layout, but instead of creating a new row, it makes its components smaller.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use
a [`FlexLayout`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.0.8/com/vaadin/flow/component/orderedlayout/FlexLayout.html)
with
[wrapping](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.0.8/com/vaadin/flow/component/orderedlayout/FlexLayout.html#setFlexWrap(com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.FlexLayout.FlexWrap)).
The default direction (column) and a wrap will give you the behaviour, that items
added to the layout will use the space they need (make sure to
"un-specifiy" where needed) and once the horizontal screen space is used up, break into the next line.